# computing P(a∧b) given P(a) and P(b) empirical distributions over 2D space

Tags: probability, discrete-data, joint-distribution

I know this is really basic but I have been unable to find anything to confirm or refute my understanding.  Suppose two discrete, independent, empirical random variables $A$ and $B$ which are functions of a two-dimensional grid (e.g. measurements taken at regularly spaced locations on the ground).  I have $A$ and $B$ as matrices, and I want to compute the matrix giving $A \wedge B$.  I *think* the correct way to do this is to multiply A element-by-element with B, but it then seems to be necessary to renormalize, and that makes me wonder if I'm doing something wrong, even though for trivial cases it gives the right answer.

Here's an example of a trivial case (numeric python):

```
>>> A
array([[ 0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.    ],
       [ 0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.    ],
       [ 0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.    ],
       [ 0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.    ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ]])

>>> B
array([[ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625],
       [ 0.    ,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625],
       [ 0.    ,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625],
       [ 0.    ,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625,  0.0625]])

>>> C = A * B
>>> C
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.00390625,  0.00390625,  0.00390625,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.00390625,  0.00390625,  0.00390625,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.00390625,  0.00390625,  0.00390625,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])

>>> C / sum(sum(C))
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.11111111,  0.11111111,  0.11111111,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.11111111,  0.11111111,  0.11111111,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.11111111,  0.11111111,  0.11111111,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to convince myself that multiply-and-then-renormalize is the correct procedure here, by applying Bayes' Theorem.  Paraphrasing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference#Inference_over_exclusive_and_exhaustive_possibilities):

> Suppose a set of independent and identically distributed events $\{E\}$ which may be explained by any one of a set of *mutually exclusive* models $\{M\}$.  Before the first inference step, $\{P(M_m)\}$ is a set of *initial prior probabilities*. These must sum to 1, but are otherwise arbitrary.  Upon observing event $E \in \{E\}$, the prior $P(M)$ of each model is updated to the posterior $P(M \mid E)$ according to the rule
>
> $$P(M \mid E) = \frac{P(E \mid M)\:P(M)}{\sum_m {P(E \mid M_m)\: P(M_m)}}$$

The matrix I called `A` can be construed as holding the priors $\{P(M)\}$, and the matrix I called `B` can be construed as holding the likelihoods $\{P(E\mid M)\}$.  Then the elementwise multiplication `C = A * B` computes the numerators of the above equation, and the aggregation `sum(sum(C))` computes the denominator.